# css positioning problems with navigation

Tags: html, css, navigation

I'm not exactly sure if the navigation is properly written, but the issue does not always occur, it either occurs during initial website load or bit later on ones user browse few pages. The problem occurs with contents being positioned right, the content does not keep inline with the rest of the navigation and simply shifts down by about 6-10px to bottom.

HTML

```
<div class="nav">
     <ul>
         <li><a href="./" class="brand">ESGator Hosting</a></li>
         <span class="right">
             <li><a href="plans.php">Plans</a></li>
             <li><a href="minecraft.php">Minecraft</a></li>
             <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
             <li><a href="support.php">Support</a></li>

             <li><a href="https://esgator.com/panel" class="button"><i class="icon-lock"></i> cPanel</a></li>
             <li><a href="https://esgator.com/mail" class="button" style="margin-left:6px;"><i class="icon-envelope"></i> Mail</a></li>
             <!-- not used <li><a href="feedback.php" class="button feedback" style="margin-left:6px;"><i class="icon-heart"></i></a></li> -->
             </span>
     </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
ul, ol, li {
font-size : 1em;
line-height : 1.6;
list-style : none;
}
.nav {
background : transparent;
width : 100%;
display : block;
position : fixed;
top : 0;
z-index : 100;
}
.add-bg {
background : #0a0a0a;
}
.static-bg {
background : #0a0a0a;
}
.nav ul {
width : auto;
max-width : 1024px;
min-width : 640px;
margin : 24px auto;
padding : 8px 0;
}
.nav li {
display : inline;
}
.nav a {
padding : 8px 0;
margin-left : 16px;
color : #7f848a;
font-size : 0.875em;
font-weight : 700;
text-transform : uppercase;
text-decoration : none;
transition : all 400ms;
text-align : left;
}
.nav a:hover, .nav a:focus {
color : #ffffff;
transition : all 400ms;
}
.nav a.active {
color : #ffffff;
}
.nav, .right {
float : right;
}
.nav a.brand {
color : #ffffff;
font-size : 0.875em;
font-weight : 700;
text-transform : uppercase;
text-decoration : none;
margin-left : 0;
transition : all 400ms;
}
.nav a.brand:hover, .nav a.brand:focus {
color : #f14f4f;
transition : all 400ms;
}
.nav a.button {
padding : 8px 10px;
background : #5aac6a;
color : #ffffff;
border-radius : 3px;
border-bottom : 2px solid #5a8a53;
transition : all 400ms;
}
.nav a.button:hover {
background : #6ca04d;
border-bottom : 2px solid #618f44;
color : #ffffff;
transition : all 400ms;
}
.nav a.button.feedback {
color : #f14f4f;
background : #eeeeee;
border-bottom-color : #d4d4d4;
}
.nav a.button.feedback:hover {
color : #f14f4f;
background : #dce0df;
border-bottom-color : #c4c8c7;
transition : all 400ms;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f9cFP/

Alternatively you can refer to actual website to see what I mean here is a live page with footer and navigation being broken, esgator.com/mail

Answer (score 0):

Maybe :

```
.nav, .right {
    text-align: right;
}
```

instead of :

```
.nav, .right {
    float : right;
}
```

Float create problems sometimes.

Comment: Nope, I would have used that. Its probably the entire CSS for navigation is slightly messed up. Well its alright I will just rewrite it.